# Iterate over pandas rows and using shift() in if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to iterate over a dataframe, then apply the shift() function. It gives me the error: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'shift'

Any simple way to do this while keeping the iteration? It should only show the last index value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['B'].shift(1) >= 4:
    print(index)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? you can save the previous value in a variable, but please explain your goal as a loop is probably not necessary

Comment: Thanks, the above is a simple example. Basically, I have a dataframe of stock data, where one column is the stock price. If the 'previous' stock price is above my target level, then I want the 'following' row to show True. I want this done in the iteration.

Comment: see the edit in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The loop approach would be to use a variable:

```
prev = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if prev is not None and prev >= 4:
    print(index)
  prev = row['B']
```

Output:

```
2
```

However, if you can, use vectorial code:

```
out = df.index[df['B'].shift().ge(4)]

# if needed to print
print(*out, sep='\n')
```

###### edit

"*If the 'previous' price is above my target level, then I want the following row to show True*"

```
df['previous_B_over_target'] = df['B'].shift().ge(4)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C  previous_B_over_target
0   0   2   3                   False
1   0   4   1                   False
2  10  20  30                    True
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your loop approach, which appears to work. Due to other conditions in my longer code, I need to use a loop approach.

Comment: @Geo sometimes you need. Still be aware that `iterrows` is very expensive as it builds Series. You might also want to try `df.itertuples`

Comment: Cool, i'll look into that, never knew that existed. I have also heard iterrows is much more system intensive. Thx